# golang unit test failed Expected nil, but got: "null\n"

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

First of all i'm trying to learn golang. I tried unit testing my handler in golang as using testify package . When run the my test i got this error -> **Expected nil, but got: "null\n"** . I was surprised that it showed the value returned from the method as null. As far as I know golangte has nil instead of null. what would be the reason?

```
my handler test file

package entities

import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

type mock struct {
    create  func(user User) error
    getById func(id uuid.UUID) *User
}

var userJson = `{"id":"e918b0bc-76f3-4380-a1fb-a14ca5a08fc3","name":"Jon Snow","email":"jon@jon.com"}`

func (m *mock) Create(user User) error     { return m.create(user) }
func (m *mock) GetById(id uuid.UUID) *User { return m.getById(id) }

func TestCreate(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    //Arrange
    e := echo.New()
    expectedStatusCode := http.StatusCreated
    m := &mock{create: func(user User) error { return nil }}
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/", strings.NewReader(userJson))
    req.Header.Set(echo.HeaderContentType, echo.MIMEApplicationJSON)
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
    server := NewUserHandler(m)

    //Act
    server.Create(c)

    //Assert
    assert.Equal(t, expectedStatusCode, rec.Code)
    assert.Nil(t, rec.Body.String())
}


my handler

func (u *userHandler) Create(e echo.Context) error {

    var user User
    err := json.NewDecoder(e.Request().Body).Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        e.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
    }
    u.userService.Create(user)
    if err != nil {
        e.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }
    return e.JSON(http.StatusCreated, nil)
}

 my user service

 func (u *userService) Create(user User) (err error) {
    err = u.userRepo.Create(user)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending back JSON. When you marshal nil, it becomes "null".

In your test you do

```
assert.Nil(t, rec.Body.String())
```

and `rec.Body` is the JSON encoded nil (i.e. "null")

In fact, because `rec.Body.String()` returns a `string`, and not `*string`, this test could never pass.

Comment: So how can I check that error is nil?

Comment: Well you wouldn't use `e.JSON(http.StatusCreated, nil)`, you would want to use `e.NoContent(http.StatusCreated)`